# Initialize variable with big number when searching for smallest value

Tags: python, arrays, list, initialization

Let's say I've got a `list` called `positions` with the following values:

```
positions = [
    [148, 23],
    [31, 89 ],
    [102, 89],
    [60, 100],
    [46, 41 ]
]
```

This list is basically a list of (X | Y) coordinates.
Now I want to get the smallest X coordinate and the smallest Y coordinate of this list.

I'm currently using the following code:

```
minX = minY = 1000000
for point in position:
    if point[0] < minX:
        minX = point[0]
    if point[1] < minY:
        minY = point[1]
```

You probably notice that for now I **initialize `minX` and `minY` with `1000000`**, so that it will get lowered by the foor loop.

What I eventually want to get:

```
minX = 31
minY = 23
```

### Question:

With what value should I initialize these two variables, what is good coding style and bug free?

Comment: You can use `sys.maxint` or just initialize them with the first element of your list and start looping with the second.

Comment: Of course that's what I *could do*, but I'm asking for the **best coding practice** without redundancy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*EDIT:* When reviewing my answer to provide a detailed explanation of what happens, I recognized my solution does not match your criteria, since you wanted to find the smallest x value and independently the smallest y value. My solution only provided the tuple with the smallest x value. Not only that, but it did this in an unnecessarily complicated way, since a simple `minx, miny = min(*positions)` would have yielded the same result as my `minx, miny = min(zip(*zip(*positions)))`. As explained later on, I transpose the input two times, which gives back the original input. Yeah, I know - good job! So I will change my answer but still provide some explanation for my original code.

The shiny new solution:

```
>>> minX, minY = map(min, *positions)
>>> minX
31
>>> minY
23
```

Now to the promised explanation part:

```
minX, minY = map(min, *positions)
```

The star/asterisk is used for [argument list unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). This means, that instead of the single list `positions`, all items contained will be fed to the `map` function as separate arguments. In this case, this would translate to `map(min, [148, 23], [31, 89], [102, 89], [60, 100], [46, 41])`.

```
minX, minY = map(min, *positions)
```

Now let's have a look at [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#map):

> Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable, yielding the results. If additional iterable arguments are passed, function must take that many arguments and is applied to the items from all iterables in parallel.

So `map` will apply the [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#min) function to the *items* of all iterables in parallel. This translates to: apply `min` to all first items (the x values), then apply `min` to all second items (the y values). As expected, `min` each time returns the smallest argument it receives.

---

Bonus content:

in my original solution I (over)used a neat trick:

```
zip(*positions)
```

Now what does [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip) do in combination with tuple unpacking?

> Returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th
>   element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.

So the resulting first tuple will contain every first element of the input arguments:

```
[148, 23], [31, 89], [102, 89], [60, 100], [46, 41] ==> [(148, 31, 102, 60, 46), (23, 89, 89, 100, 41)]
```

This is equal to the [transpose of a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose), when you view each sublist of the list as a separate row of your matrix.

Comment: Just like with @Psidom 's answer, could you explain what's happening there? And furthermore, what do the asteriks (`*`) mean?

Answer (score 2):

You could just initialize them at the first set of values.
Like:

```
minX, minY = position[0]
```

These means even if they are the smallest, it does not matter. And if you don't want to you don't then have to loop though this pair either:

```
for point in positions[1:]:
    # loop code...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
minX, minY = map(min, zip(*positions))

minX
# 31

minY
# 23
```

With `zip(*...)` you have the list transposed, with x coordinates as the first sublist and y coordinates as the second sublist, and then use `map(min,...)` to calculate the minimum x and minimum y correspondingly.

Comment: Could you maybe explain what you're doing there?

Answer (score 1):

This is another pattern you could use. It can be applied, obviously with modification, to other situations.

```
>>> positions = [ [148, 23], [31, 89 ], [102, 89], [60, 100], [46, 41 ] ]
>>> minX = None
>>> minY = None
>>> for x,y in positions:
...     minX = min(x, minX) if minX else x
...     minY = min(y, minY) if minY else y
```

Set each required result to `None`. Since each item in `positions` consists of two items you can use the for-loop to unpack each item into an `x` and a `y` value. Now, if `minX` has not been calculated then set its value to `x`, otherwise set it to the minimum of itself and `x`.

Answer (score 0):

```
minX = minY = float('inf')
```

will result in a float representation of infinity, which is greater than all other numbers. This is a reasonable way to do this in python 2.7.

in python 3,

```
import math
minX = minY = math.inf
```

has been added, which is cleaner.